# PNP high side switching with 100 mA load

Tags: transistors, switching

[image: schematic]

I have this circuit to detect tamper status using a switch. When the switch is pressed (ON) then GND is provided to the base of Q3 (2N3906), so that transistor will be in the saturation region and can get 12 V with 100 mA load across R20. When the switch is OFF, then a positive voltage appears on the base of Q3 & there is 0 V across R20.

Also when the switch is pressed (ON), then GND is provided to the base of Q4 (2N3904), so that transistor will be in the cutoff region and LED D7 will be off. When the switch is OFF, then a positive voltage appears on the base of Q4 & LED D7 will be ON.

I am at a learning stage, please guide me to calculate the resistor values & other suggestions with explanations so that circuit can work for a long time.

---

I am really sorry for the wrong text initially. Circuit diagram also updated.

Comment: To start with, your 3906 is placed incorrectly. The current is supposed to go in the direction of the arrow, your Base-Emitter arrow is looking up. Swap emitter and collector for starters

Comment: re-draw the schematic so that the four resistors, R14, R15, R21 AND R25, are all oriented vertically in a single column, with +12 V at top and GND at bottom .... that will make it easier for you to see what voltages are present at every point in the circuit .... include R7 in parallel with R14/R15 if it is actually included in the circuit

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the "tamper" output will always be high with this circuit- R21 will cause Q3 to remain on, albeit with a bit less base current than when the switch is pressed.

2N3906 is not a great transistor if your load current is actually 100mA, as the gain plummets above about 30mA. I would suggest a [2N4403](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n4403-d.pdf).  If you operate that with  a base current of about 10-15mA you'll get low Vce(sat).
A rule of thumb is that Ic/Ib should be around 10 to 20, with the latter more appropriate for a transistor that has an hFE of >100 at the desired current. That calls for R14 to be reduced to about 1K. R15 and R7 do more-or-less the same thing, so let's get rid of R15.

Your LED current will be in the 20mA range with a 500 ohm series resistor. I suggest trying it with at least 1K instead, maybe 2K or 4.7K is bright enough with a modern LED. To have the LED turn off when the tamper is detected without the problem mentioned, you can connect it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcgpjC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's a hidden issue with this circuit in that the electrolytic cap will cause the transistor to switch very slowly, which is at bit hard on it when it's conducting 50mA with 6V across it (assuming a 12V/100mA load resistance). It should be safe enough in this case, but it is something to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Transistor Circuit]

When switch closed 100R resistor limits capacitor discharge current through switch to reduce switch wear.

When switch is closed, base of BC327 is pulled down to approx 11.3V pulling about 1.5mA out of the transistor's base. This is sufficient base current to cater for your 100mA load. Minimum hFE of BC327 is 100 which is higher than the 2N3906's minimum hFE. Q1 is configured in common emitter mode.

When switch is closed, base of BC548 is pulled almost to ground switching off the LED. BC548 is configured in emitter follower mode.

When switch is opened, base of BC327 is pulled up to about 11.9V switching off the BC327 and enabling its collector to fall to 0V. Simmultaneously R2 & R4 now supply base current to Q2 switching on the LED.

Comment: When used as a switch, BJTs must be assumed to be operating with a gain of 10 to 20, with 10 being a more conservative and bulletproof figure.

Answer (score 0):

With R20 at 2k, there is no way you are going to draw 100 mA.

Assuming that 100 mA is the desired collector current, if you want the load voltage to be within about 1 volt of the supply voltage, the gain of the transistor should be assumed to be about 10. With a very low Vce the transistor is in saturation, and gain is low.

This means that you need a base current of about 10 mA. In turn, this means that R14 should be about 1 k. For what it's worth, some texts suggest assuming a saturation gain of 20, in which case 1.8 k will work just fine.

It really depends on how conservative a design you want to make, and how low you want Vce to be.